# Rename/Move a Directory if locked elsewhere

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a C# winform app.

I have a directory 'd:\mydir'

In my code I rename it to 'd:\mydir2'

If File Explorer is open and the 'mydir' is selected it will return a permissions error.

Is it possible to override this permission denied and forcibly rename it despite whatever other external application/process is accessing the same directory (or/and its contents)?

thanks

Comment: This is the sort of thing where you have to imagine "what if everyone did this".  IE if there was an override to say "I know what I'm doing, rename this folder", what would happen if the other process said "I know what I'm doing, don't let anyone override my lock on this folder".  Or put yourself in the other processes shoes - "Why did this file disappear from underneath me, despite me having acquired a read/write lock on it".  Not saying it's not possible, but needs careful thought - file locks are there for a reason.

Comment: File locks are controlled by the operating system. It's not possible to override them with an API call.

Comment: Hi chaps, yes, whilst i was away making a coffee just now :) I did consider the 'what if scenario as well' :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Possible** : Yes ( Assuming you have admin permissions)

- Get all processes `Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();`
- Filter out process who are running from that directory by title tag (Risky)
- Forcefully ( or show a pop up opinion from user) close those
  processes
- Close file explorer window
- Rename the Directory

**Should you do it** : No

*Why :* As Suggested by *James Thorpe* in comments What if it's a program half way through saving a large document, if you kill it, you've got a probably corrupted file.

Comment: I deem it bad user experience if someone closes my explorer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time.  I agree with @Dawnkeeper on this i am afraid. Also, I am concerned with other processes/apps  locking as well

Comment: How about we show a popup and give option to user if he want to close it on his own or forcefully by c# code ?

Comment: @Manish Your process may not have access to even do so.  Also imagine an RDP environment where the file lock is acquired by another user in a different session.  Killing off other processes (even if you do have privileges to do so) is just not good

Comment: @James I get your concern. But if you don't kill process from that directory, I don't see other option available to rename directory even if you have admin permissions.

Comment: Exactly - but the other processes probably have a good reason for having that lock.  What if it's a program half way through saving a large document, if you kill it, you've got a probably corrupted file.

Comment: Agreed, Updated Answer.